# Find the type of Object passed in a param method

Tags: java, android

This is a HomeWork And I'm having some difficulty, I'm trying to create a BaseActivity that will be extended by all my Activities. I would like to make a method that will configure and show my fragments directly in the BaseActivity so inside the Activity I will just have to pass 2 params (Fragment fragment, int frame layout)

```java
    public void configureAndShowFragment(BaseFragment fragment, int layout) {
        fragment = (BaseFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(layout);
        if (fragment == null && findViewById(layout) != null) {
            fragment = new fragment // <== init fragment here
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(layout, fragment)
                    .commit();
        }
    }
```

I added a comment where I'm having some difficulty, "Init fragment here" my goals here is to be able to initialize my fragment with the correct type, example "new Mainfragment, new DetailsFragment" My problem here is that I would like to do some testing on my param fragment so I can get to know what is the type of my param fragment so I can initialize it with the correct type.

[image]

Comment: Your question seems clear, unlike the rest of the post and the code in it. Are you trying to know the type of an object ? if its from a sub class of your base class ?

Comment: ```x.getClass().getName()``` gets you name of the class.

Comment: this is the code from my BaseActivity, and my other activities will extend it and will use this method. What I want to do is be able to initialize it with the correct type that will be passed in the variable fragment, I cant just do fragment = new MainFragment because it can be another one, I will have a few Fragments so it has to be checked so I know which fragment was passed and I can initiate it with the correct type. I hope you did understand what is expected. thank you for your help.

Comment: ```BaseFragment fragment``` is passed as a parameter and not read btw. And the class type you want to instantiate from, how are you supposed to know it ? In the block of condition ```(fragment == null && findViewById(layout) != null)``` fragment is null. I dont see in your code an information suggestion what the type of the fragment should be.

Comment: I added a screenshot hopefully you will have enough detail to understand, The solution you give me with your second comment won't work it will produce a null pointer exception because at the moment we start the method the object is still null. I was wondering if there was any possibility to know because inside the MainActivity the main fragment that will be passed as a param is not initiated but its a type of MainFragment and I was wondering if there was any way we could detect the type even if it not yet initiated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this, using reflection getting type of fragment initially then creating if you cannot find it by ID.

```
public void configureAndShowFragment(BaseFragment fragment, int layout) throws ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchMethodException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, InstantiationException {
        if (fragment == null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("fragment cannot be null");
        }

        String fragmentClassName = fragment.getClass().getName();

        fragment = (BaseFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(layout);
        if (fragment == null && findViewById(layout) != null) {
            Class<?> clazz = Class.forName(fragmentClassName);
            Constructor<?> ctor = clazz.getConstructor();
            fragment = (BaseFragment) ctor.newInstance(); <== init fragment here
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(layout, fragment)
                    .commit();
        }
    }
```

despite being casted to `BaseFragment`, if you do `fragment.getClass().getName()`, you will have the sub type that fragment had initially.